# How to update absence table of employee master data in SDK?

Tags: sapb1

I have a problem in SAP B1 SDK,

Actually I can add employee in employee master data by using SDK like below codes

```
$oOrder=$mycomp->GetBusinessObject(171);
$oOrder->firstName="Schadrack";
$oOrder->lastName="Rurangwa";
$RetCode=$oOrder->Add;
```

But now I want to add absence line to the existing employee in SAP B1, how can I add absence or update the table (HEM1) of absence in SAP B1 SDK, I used PHP but I need sample even if it is vb

Please anyone can help me

Comment: I don't have a code sample for the SDK but when adding this sort of data via Service Layer you would add to the EmployeeAbsenceInfoLines of the employee object. Should be something similar in SDK.

Comment: Yes, but as I think we have to have reference of Absence table before adding data in HEM1 because we have other tables of Education, Reviews, Previous Employment and Time Sheet in Employees Master Data

Answer (score 1):

Vb.net Sample from https://answers.sap.com/questions/3710838/insert-new-records-doesnt-work.html

```
Dim abs As SAPbobsCOM.EmployeeAbsenceInfo
Dim oei As SAPbobsCOM.EmployeesInfo
oei = oCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oEmployeesInfo)
abs = oei.AbsenceInfo
abs.Add()
abs.SetCurrentLine(1)
abs.EmployeeID = 2
abs.FromDate = "2008-01-01 12:00:00"
abs.ToDate = "2008-01-01 12:30:00"

abs.Add()
abs.SetCurrentLine(2)
abs.EmployeeID = 2
abs.FromDate = "2008-01-02 10:00:00"
abs.ToDate = "2008-01-02 11:00:00"
abs.Add()
Dim err_code As Integer
Dim err_msg As String
err_msg = ""
err_code = oei.Add()
If err_code <> 0 Then
oCompany.GetLastError(err_code, err_msg)
End If
```